# Add text - Inner html by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="list">
<li id="item">How are</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add "You" to "How are you".
Pure JS

```
document.getElementById("item").innerHTML += "You";
```

jQuery? How to code it by jQuery?

Comment: $("#item").html(),try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's `.text()` or `.html()` to set or get the text/html content.

Below is the example.

```js
let item = $('#item');
item.text(item.text() + ' You');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
<li id="item">How are</li>
</ul>
```